# Is it possible to have a contract with a single constructor that extends both the ERC20 and ERC721?

Tags: dapps

Is it possible to have a contract with a single constructor that extends both the ERC20 and ERC721 contract while implementing their respective functions as in the example above?

```
contract K3CEARTH is ERC20, ERC721, Ownable { 
    constructor() ERC20("Token name", "TKN") ERC721("NFT name ", "XFT") {
```

If so, please provide a code example.
NB: I tried and it can work. It only remains to better specify the functions having the same names and/or the same variables or parameters. This is where I need your help.

The idea is to centralize the automatic management of the contract of a platform where all transactions are made only with ERC20 tokens, even for the purchase of NFT (ERC721).
This has several advantages, including traceability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to extend both ERC20 and ERC721 into new custom contract.
To avoid the naming conflicts between functions in both ERC20 and ERC721 contracts, you need to override the functions in the child contract with override modifiers. In this example, we override the _beforeTokenTransfer and _burn functions from ERC721.

```
contract K3CEARTH is ERC20, ERC721, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("Token name", "TKN") ERC721("NFT name", "XFT") {}

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Naveed Ali,
Thank you for agreeing to help me.
I am still waiting for your help on my code.